# Hadoop + Spark: Why is the worker node unable to connect to the ResourceManager?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm using Hadoop 3.3.1 and Spark 3.2.0 to build a windows cluster consisting of two nodes: a manager (running resource and node manager) and a worker (running a node manager).

Despite seemingly having configured the yarn-site.xml correctly, I keep getting the error "Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030" which causes the application to get stuck in the state "ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM" because the ResourceManager couldn't be reached:

```
2021-11-26 13:28:01,700 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://FQHN_WORKER:50059
2021-11-26 13:28:01,804 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: Created YarnClusterScheduler
...
2021-11-26 13:28:02,337 INFO client.DefaultNoHARMFailoverProxyProvider: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8030
2021-11-26 13:28:02,395 INFO yarn.YarnRMClient: Registering the ApplicationMaster
2021-11-26 13:28:05,568 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
2021-11-26 13:28:33,223 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8030. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

My yarn-site.xml looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>FQHN_MANAGER</value>
  <final>true</final>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Requesting the configuration from the worker node via http://FQHN_WORKER:8042/conf, it seems to pick up my configuration correctly:

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>FQHN_MANAGER</value>
  <final>false</final>
  <source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
...
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>FQHN_MANAGER:8030</value>
  <final>true</final>
  <source>yarn-site.xml</source>
</property>
```

I also did the following to no avail:

- disabled other network interfaces on both nodes
- disabled the firewalls on both nodes
- tested port 8030 with telnet from worker to manager (works fine)
- checked hosts file (rebooted to "apply" changes)

As a workaround, portforwarding 0.0.0.0:8030 to FQHN_MANAGER:8030 on the worker node works, but is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: How can I do the portforwarding on the worker node ? I'm kinda new to hadoop and having the same issue as you now.

Comment: @kp2349: Open an admin CMD on the worker node and enter (replace {ResourceManager} with the IP or fully qualified hostname of the node that runs the resourcemanager):

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8030 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8030 connectaddress={ResourceManager}". The port 8030 is the default value of yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address, you have to replace it by what you defined in your yarn-site.xml (cf. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)